# pfSense networking/routing troubleshooting

Tags: networking, routing, freebsd, pfsense

I have set up a pfSense virtual machine with two networks adaptators :

- WAN : 192.168.0.27/24 that is connected to an other router 192.168.0.1 to get internet access
- LAN : 172.16.0.1/16 that is connected to the LAN 192.168.1.0/24 ( but that's not the point here )

On my pfSense I've got an internet access but when a client is behind the pfSense, I can contact the first hop ( 172.16.0.1 ) , the second hop ( 192.168.0.27 ) , the third ( 192.168.0.1 second router interface) so the routing is done well on the virtual Machine but I can't reach the Internet on a client...

If someone see where is the problem , I'll be glad to ear his answer ! Thanks for reading and have a nice day :)

Comment: Could you share the routing tables you configured? Are you using DHCP to configure the client's network settings? If so could you share that configuration as well? 
Can you share the outputs from traceroute?

Comment: traceroute stops to the first hop ( 172.16.0.1) so this is definitively a routing problem

Comment: I agree it's a routing problem, hence my questions :) Without more information it's hard to say what configuration is missing. From what you stated in your question it looks like you can also reach second and third hop but that's not the case ?

Comment: After the "reset factory settings" it worked !

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Have you correctly configured the default routes for each router? Does each router know who to ask about networks it does not know?

The default route of 192.168.0.1 should be your internet provider's default gateway. The default route of 192.168.0.27 and 172.16.0.1 should be 192.168.0.1, and the default route of the clients on 172.16.0.0 should be 172.16.0.1.

It's difficult to know without knowing more about your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer

Well on pfSense I can't tell him to use the 192.168.0.1 (box card ) or even 192.168.0.27 ( the pfSense card ) on the LAN card which is configured in 172.16.0.0 /16 , I can now see what is missing but can't configure it... The  route that says " all packets from 172.16.0.0/16 to 192.168.0.0/24 ( or any networks ) should use this gateway 192.168.0.1" is missing but generates an error on pfSense

Comment: Is there inverse route known to the internet router? Is that router aware of the underlying networks containing your hosts?

Comment: Hi guys , I made a "factory reset" of the pfSense and it worked...

Thank you all for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I made a "factory reset" of the pfSense and it worked... Thank you all for your reply